# Accessing a member's banner in discord.py

Tags: python, image-processing, discord, discord.py

I am making an image profile command. I would like to access the member's banner for this. Is there any way we can do that in discord.py?

[image: Banner]

If it is not clear what i mean by banner then, the image with the blue background is the banner. I would like to access that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In discord.py v2.0 you can use

```py
# You may have to re-fetch the user for the banner to work properly
user = await bot.fetch_user(user.id)
banner_url = user.banner.url # The URL of the banner
```

Before v2.0, there is a hacky way to get the banner by directly using the API

```py
req = await bot.http.request(discord.http.Route("GET", "/users/{uid}", uid=user.id))
banner_id = req["banner"]
if banner_id:
    banner_url = f"https://cdn.discordapp.com/banners/{user.id}/{banner_id}?size=1024"
else:
    # The user doesn't have a banner, do what you want
    # In many forks, User.accent_color exists so you
    # may want to check if your library supports that first
    pass
```

To install discord.py v2.0 you should run

```sh
pip install -U git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py
```

Comment: can you tell me how do i upgrade and check my discord,py version?

Comment: `pip install -U git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py`

Comment: thanks that helped but what i would like to do is if a person does not have a banner then i would like to get the default colour one. Anyway i can do that?

Comment: No as far as I know

Comment: Hey @NishilSheth `enhanced-discord.py`, `pycord`, `nextcord`, and many more have support for `User.accent_color` to get the default color one now. If you are using any of the forks you may want to use that

Comment: Thank you. I already use pycord and nextcord. During that time, V2 was in beta so I thought I should ask a question here.

Answer (score 0):

The full command would be like:

```
@bot.command()
async def banner(ctx, user:discord.Member):
    if user == None:
        user = ctx.author
    req = await bot.http.request(discord.http.Route("GET", "/users/{uid}", uid=user.id))
    banner_id = req["banner"]
    # If statement because the user may not have a banner
    if banner_id:
        banner_url = f"https://cdn.discordapp.com/banners/{user.id}/{banner_id}?size=1024"
    await ctx.send(f"{banner_url}")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True, aliases= ['bn'])
async def banner(ctx, *, user:commands.UserConverter=None):
    if user == None:
        member = ctx.author
    else:
        member = user
    usr = await bot.fetch_user(member.id)
    if usr.banner:
        banner = usr.banner.url
        bannerEmbed=nextcord.Embed(
            title='',
            description=f"**[banner]({banner})**",
            color=0x000001
        )
        bannerEmbed.set_author(name=f'{usr.name}#{usr.discriminator}', icon_url=usr.display_avatar.url)
        bannerEmbed.set_image(url=banner)
        await ctx.send(embed=bannerEmbed)
    elif usr.accent_color:
        
        uc = str(usr.accent_color).format(hex).strip('#')
        
        colorEmbed=nextcord.Embed(
            title='',
            description=f"**[banner]({f'https://singlecolorimage.com/get/{uc}/400x100'})**",
            color=0x000001
        )
        
        colorEmbed.set_author(name=f'{usr.name}#{usr.discriminator}', icon_url=usr.display_avatar.url)
        colorEmbed.set_image(url=f'https://singlecolorimage.com/get/{uc}/400x100')
        await ctx.send(embed=colorEmbed)
    else:
        bnerrEmbed=nextcord.Embed(
            title='',
            description='banner/color not assigned',
            color=0x000001
        )
        bnerrEmbed.set_author(name=f'{usr.name}#{usr.discriminator}', icon_url=usr.display_avatar.url)
        await ctx.send(embed=bnerrEmbed)
@banner.error
async def need_mention(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, UserNotFound):
        await ctx.send("user not found")
    else:
        print(error)
```

Here is the second edit for the banner command that works with: [nextcord API Wrapper](https://nextcord.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) | [nextcord's Github](https://github.com/nextcord)

This command will access the user's banner (if applicable) and display it:

If there is no banner but an accent color is assigned, it will display the accent color as the displayed banner.

If no accent color or banner is assigned, the command will send a message to the channel stating that the user has no assigned banner/color.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).