# Member discord Banner

Tags: python, discord.py

I get through crutches a link to the user discord banner, how can I convert it into a picture to display in a profile.`

```
     req = await self.bot.http.request(discord.http.Route("GET", "/users/{uid}", uid=member.id))
    banner_id = req['banner']

    if banner_id:
        banner_url = f"https://cdn.discordapp.com/banners/{member.id}/{banner_id}?size=1024"
        await ctx.send(banner_url)
```

`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing a member's banner in discord.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68689808/accessing-a-members-banner-in-discord-py)

Answer (score 0):

As mentionned in [Accessing a member's banner in discord.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68689808/accessing-a-members-banner-in-discord-py), you can simply do

```py
await ctx.send(member.banner.url)
```